# How do get a common elements from two datasets, where one dataset has only one column and other dataset set has ten columns

Tags: r

Suppose I have two datasets

```
dataset = a
V1
an
ak

dataset =b
V1 V2 V3
an 23 45
jk 45 89
ak 45 78
lm 56 79
```

Now I want dataset C to be like this,

```
V1 V2 V3
an 23 45
ak 45 78.
```

I tried in many ways but its not giving me exactly what I want. Please help me

Comment: `b[b$V1 %in% a$V1, ]` or `b[match(a$V1, b$V1), ]`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. My favourite is `%in%` because it can be applied to a large number of different object types.

```
b[b$V1 %in% a$V1,]
```